# Remove google prettyprint padding?

Tags: html, css, pretty-print

I started using the Google prettyprint tool today as I am starting a new project, however, there seems to be unnecessary padding where I think the numbers are supposed to go, but I'm not quite sure.

Anyways, how can I remove this padding/margin?

I have tried things such as `padding: 0 !important;`, `margin: 0 !important;`, `text-align: left !important;` and `float: left !important;` but to no avail.

Image example:

[image: Image Example]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=css&amp;skin="></script>
    <style>
      table {
        border: 0;
        width: 100%
        }

      th {
        text-align: left;
        }

      #code-box {
        border-left: 5px solid #5C00AC;
        }

      #no-border {
        border: none !important;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ModPE API</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>Members</h2>
    <hr>
    <h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;">ArmorType</h4>
    <p>Armor Types.</p>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>       
        <th>Description</th>
      <tr>
        <td>helmet</td>
        <td>int</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>chestplate</td>
        <td>int</td>        
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>leggings</td>
        <td>int</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>boots</td>
        <td>int</td>        
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h4>Example:</h4>
    <div id="code-box">
      <pre class="prettyprint" id="no-border">
        print(ArmorType.chestplate);
      </pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is caused by the whitespace characters in your HTML. You don't need to edit the CSS.

Change this:

```
  <pre class="prettyprint" id="no-border">
    print(ArmorType.chestplate);
  </pre>
```

To this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint" id="no-border">print(ArmorType.chestplate);</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want indentation for readability, the same effect can be achieved just by removing the whitespace after the carriage return. Just to be clear, there needs to be no whitespace before the pre open and ending tags as well.

```
<pre class="prettyprint" id="no-border">
  print(ArmorType.chestplate);
</pre>

<!-- Becomes -->

<pre class="prettyprint" id="no-border">
print(ArmorType.chestplate);
</pre>
```